# Sound waves into sine waves

Tags: waves, mathematics

Can anyone explain the equation $\sin(fπx)$ where $f$ is a sound wave's frequency in Hz?

I am trying to convert sound waves into graphed sine waves by using their frequency but don't understand the formula. Why are we multiplying by $\pi$?

If anyone knows another equation to graph the sound like a sine wave I would be very grateful... I found this equation online and it doesn't seem right...

Comment: Frequency is one over the period. So by definition, the sound wave repeats itself every $f^{-1}$ units of time. The wave at time zero must be equal to the wave at time $f^{-1}$. This is true for the expression you give. It would not be without the pi.

Comment: If you want your equation to describe a moving wave, the (f) and (x) should be separated    : a = A sin[2π(f t - x/λ)].

Answer (score 2):

The amplitude of a sine wave with frequency $f$ Hertz at time $t$ seconds is

$$a(t) = A_0\sin(2\pi ft)$$

where $A_0$ is the maximum amplitude. The argument to the $\sin$ function is in radians, which is why we need to multiply by $2\pi$, which is one revolution in radians. This means that the amplitude $a(t)$ repeats every $\frac 1 f$ seconds.